# PHP How do I rand float value?

Tags: php

```
$a = floatval(0.0001);
$b = floatval(0.0009);
$c = rand($a,$b); // int(0);
```

How can I get rand from `$a` to `$b` floats? 
Multiplication of `$`a and `$b` is not solution, because I don't know number of digits after dot.

Comment: addition of $a and $b??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php#75562):

An elegant way to return random float between two numbers:

```
function random_float ($min,$max) {
   return ($min+lcg_value()*(abs($max-$min)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create the random with values above 0, and devide it.

```
$a = 1;
$b = 9;
$c = rand($a, $b);
$c = $c / 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to count the number of decimals and do a `rand` on the numbers powered by this number :

```
function count_decimals($x) {
   return strlen(substr(strrchr($x+"", "."), 1));
}

function random($min, $max, $precision = 0) {
   $decimals = max(count_decimals($min), count_decimals($max)) + $precision;
   $factor = pow(10, $decimals);
   return rand($min*$factor, $max*$factor) / $factor;
}

var_dump(random(0.001, 0.009)); // 0.004
var_dump(random(0.001, 0.009, 1)); // 0.0046
var_dump(random(0.001, 0.009, 2)); // 0.00458
var_dump(random(0.001, 0.009, 5)); // 0.00458014
```

I added the `$precision` parameter so you can choose how many more decimals you want to append in your random number.